# psycopg2 Google Analytics data to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pandas, google-analytics, psycopg2, index-error

I am trying to insert data from a dataframe that i've created using an API call to GA and insert it into my postgresql database using psycopg2.
This is the code I am using:

```
garesults = df.reindex_axis(['campaign', 'adClicks', 'adCost', 'CPC', 'sessions', 'bounceRate', 'pageviewsPerSession', 'goal6ConversionRate', 'goal6Completions', 'goal6Values'], axis = 1)

gafill = garesults.fillna(value = 0)


# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=xxx password=xxx")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute a command: this creates a new table
#cur.execute("CREATE TABLE adform (campaign, campaignid, impressions, clicks );")
for row in gafill:     
     cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ga ( campaign, adClicks, adCost, CPC, sessions, bounceRate, pageviewsPerSession, goal6ConversionRate, goal6Completions, goal6Values)
                       VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9]])
```

When I run this it brings back an error message:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The commented out table create statement doesn't match the insert statement.  I'm not sure if that is the issue or merely an artifact of editing things into a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are trying to iterate over the dataframe.

Try using itertuples instead:

`for index, row in gafill.itertuples():
     .....`